# How Can I Install 3rd Gen CPU to My 2nd Gen Motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, intel-core-i5, i3

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte H61M-S2P-B3 rev 1.0
CPU: Intel Core i3-2100 3.1GHz
Graphics Card: AMD HD 6570 1GB
RAM: 2x8 1600MHz (I believe at 1333MHz)
Power Supply: Casper WIN-400PS 400 Watt
```

My issue is that I want to replace my current CPU with an Intel Core i5-3470. However, when I install the new CPU and try to power on the system, it shuts down without displaying any video output and then continuously restarts in a loop.

I've updated the BIOS to the latest version, currently running F6, but unfortunately, the problem persists. I'm not sure what the issue is, but I hope the new CPU is not faulty. I've also tried changing the fan, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Did you check the CPU compatibility list yet?

Comment: It's on the list, but the list is a bit confusing… v1.0 or 1.1?? https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S2P-B3-rev-11/support#support-cpu

Comment: Another [list](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Core_i5/i5-3470_motherboards.html) includes this motherboard as supporting the i5-3470 with firmware F6. Lists may be wrong, but perhaps it's better to consult a professional.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's "rev 1.0" so it won't support it apparently.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, and my BIOS version is F6 rn. https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S2P-B3-rev-10/support#support-cpu

Comment: @Tetsujin rev1.0

Comment: @harrymc  I took the processor to a computer technician to test it, but they told me to bring the whole computer. They don't have a suitable motherboard for testing. I will take it to them during the week

Comment: @ChanganAuto But in the support list it says for F5 version: Support Intel 3rd generation 22nm E1 stepping CPU (Ivy bridge)

Comment: The list is for rev. 1.1.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I will try another motherboard then. I hope my processor is okay.